# Dynamic key(s) in Exact object

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to declare an object type that is Exact, so it should have two keys, one is `cnt` and the other is one of the keys in an object.

```
const ICONS = { foo:'', bar:'' }

type IconNames = $Keys<typeof ICONS>;
```

Now IconNames is an enum of "foo" or "bar". So I tried this:

```
const myObj: MyObj = { cnt:5, foo:true }
type MyObj = {| cnt:number, [IconNames]:bool |}
```

but its not working.

#### Example 2

```
type Props = { blah:string, qux:string }

type MySecondObj = {| hi:boolean, bye:boolean, ...Props |}

const mySecondObj: MySecondObj = { hi:false, bye:false, blah:'ya', qux:'ok' };
```

However this does not work either. I couldn't find any search results. But this is like "dynamically adding keys" so I searched for this but got no results.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding this question. Maybe you could edit it with a concrete example of something you are trying to accomplish, and how Flow is preventing you from doing it?

Comment: Thank you very much @Nat for your attention. I removed the second example and refined the first. I will refine the second and update in a second :)

Comment: @NatMote I refined 2nd example too, I think it is of same type. Thank you sir!

Comment: I don't get any errors when I paste the second example into flow.org/try so I'm not sure what your question is. As for the first example, my guess is that this case simply has not been addressed in the type checker. What you want is for `MyObj` to allow `cnt`, `foo`, and `bar` as properties but nothing else, right? It might be worth filing a GitHub issue.

Comment: @NatMote excuse my delay. Yes sir for the first case, it should allow for `cnt`, `foo`, and `bar`, but foo and bar are mutually exclusive. So one or the other. For a max of just two keys. I'll double check my second example.

Comment: Oops I fixed up the 2nd example. It is error on flow.org/try now as well - https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKATnDgM5gC8YA3mAEYwCGAFgFzkbECWAdgHMANGACOAVwAenbvwFgAvumz4wAWSwBlPAGM4fACYB5BgCtqdAD5hWPdgzhwYeZnxEMsee4+euRAOkCSMkpLJXRUPT4uMABbLV19YzN2dQSo5PMaelt2KGYYcjx3TzyCovcWDgByLGZqkQlpargAa2rFAG4gA

Comment: @NatMote I just found solution to my example 1! :) i posted it in solutions below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to Example 1:

```
const ICONS = { foo:'', bar:'' }

type IconNames = $Keys<typeof ICONS>;

const myObj: MyObj = { cnt:5, foo:true }
type MyObj = {| cnt:number, [key:IconNames]:bool |}
```